# What is the successor to the GNURadio liveCD?

Tags: gnuradio

I used to burn and run the GNU Radio livecd - it was a very nice package that gave me a working gnuradio environment - with drivers and tools - without doing a lot of sysadmin or package management, etc.

Now, however, the GNU Radio liveCD is no longer supported nor recommended and, while still available from some places, the last release is about four years old.

What is the next best option if I want to quickly get a gnuradio environment up and running with tools like gqrx and I don't want to spend a week working through dependencies ?

Thank you.

Comment: um, you actually just... install GNU Radio? That just works these days. You can download it for windows, you can just `apt install` it on debian/ubuntu, `dnf install gnuradio gqrx` on fedora, you can get it via homebrew on OS X, anaconda/conda has one line installation... You can install it in the ubuntu that is your WSL on Windows 10, and if you want SDR hardware access, that works as long as it's an RTL-SDR and you run rtl-tcp on your host windows, or a networked SDR…

Comment: Also, really not convinced this signal processing site is the optimal place to ask for installation help, to be completely honest; the GNU Radio website has a "Getting Started" link, which will take you to installation methods. If that's no help, GNU Radio has a very active mailing list, and a very active IRC channel / Matrix server.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Thank you.  What was nice about the livecd is that it had a nice collection of other installed tools and utilities, etc., that complimented gnuradio.  It sounds like there is no real successor then ...

Comment: ... these tools can be now, mostly, also be trivially installed.